# How to make HTML table to Datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatable

I followed the below code to make a normal table into data table.. i included all the links responsible to make data table.. but still data table is not showing up.. pls resolve the error anyone?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ASSESSMENT 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
   
   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable();
       
});

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="" class="container">
        <!-- <button type="button" onclick="run()"> Click Me </button> -->
        <h1 class="text-center">Table of Data</h1>

        <!--id="example"  -->
        <table id="example" class="table ">
            <tr>
                <th>NO</th> 
                <th>API</th>
                <th>Description</th>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        const table = document.getElementById("example")
        function run() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries';
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    // getting res and to convert in json

                    let res = this.responseText;
                    let data = JSON.parse(res);
                    // console.log(data);
                    //traverse data
                    let NO =[]
                    let API = []
                    let Description = []
                    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        NO.push([i]);
                        API.push(data["entries"][i]["API"])
                        Description.push(data["entries"][i]["Description"])
                    }
                    // to create a table
                    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        let row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
                        //add cells
                        let cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
                        let cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
                        let cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

                        // to insert the data
                        cell0.innerHTML = NO [i]
                        cell1.innerHTML = API[i];
                        cell2.innerHTML = Description[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
        run()

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

shall i need to put some specific links are the above things is enough? the output shows a normal table.. i have also called the table's id in script  tag also.. is anything need to be done

Comment: Why the mix of jQuery and vanilla JS (especially why `XMLHttpRequest` and not `$.ajax`)?

Comment: Here's your code, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/d9x7r0yt/